# use globalAlpha in canvas only for part of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i want to set transparency for part of canvas 
can I use globalAlpha  like for all canvas except rectangle i create in the canvas ?

Comment: Can you not set the alpha, draw something, change the alpha, then draw the rest? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want all the canvas to have transparency except the rectangle that in the canvas if it was possible something like this

Comment: i need to have rectangle with transparency except the rectangle i create in the canvas , if it was possible ..something like this:        var can = document.getElementById('mycanvas');var context = can.getContext('2d');
context.globalAlpha = 0.2;
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0,1)';
context.fillRect(100, 100, 150, 50).removetracperencyfromrec();

Comment: Do as I suggested then. Set the alpha, draw something, change the alpha, draw the rest

Comment: i don't understand i have only one thing to draw . rectangle              if i draw the rectangle before or after setting the alpha the rectangle affected by the alpha

Comment: Use the code I provided below. Base what you have off of it

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how to make a rectangle transparent *after* you have a bunch of things drawn to the canvas you can do the following:

```
/// clear a rectangle to make canvas transparent
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';

/// set alpha using a fill color with transparency
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';

/// fill rectangle which now will become partly transparent all the way
ctx.fillRect(40, 40, 320, 320);

/// reset composite mode
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
```

### [Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/D2W9G/)

If this is not what you mean then you need to plan your drawings. As mentioned elsewhere you can set `globalAlpha` *before* you draw something, draw it, then set `globalAlpha` back before you draw the next. Each draw after setting `globalAlpha` will be drawn with that alpha value (if the fill-style, stroke-style of image alpha uses transparency as well that will be a result of the two alpha values as they are multiplied).

`globalCompositeOperation` decides *how* it will be drawn, for example on top of existing content, instead of and so forth (see an overview [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html)).

Answer (score 0):

As I've said in the comments twice, you just have to set the global alpha to what you want, draw what you want with that alpha, then change the global alpha to a new value, then draw what you want in that alpha. That can be done as follows

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0,1)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 50);
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2; 
ctx.fillRect(150,50,150,50);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PT3bB/)

Comment: the case is bit a more complex , i draw imag to the canvas before creating the rectangle and i want the part inside the canvas to be clear from alpha .